# Changing devices boot time logo of android phone

Tags: android, time, boot, graphical-logo

I want to change the logo of my phone.

How do i change the booting logo or my android phone? For example, the samsung logo that comes up during boot.

Comment: check this link http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=543095

Comment: Thank for the link vishwa,but I don't know how to use it,can you please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the original question pertains to the SAMSUNG (or your manufacturer's) logo that pops up first thing when booting, **not** the boot animation that runs afterwards. The boot animation can be changed, but the initial logo(s, as there can be two or more) seems to be somewhat evasive.

On some phones it may be found by doing a search on logo.bin ... on other phones it may be named boot.img ... on others you won't find anything.

Some devices may have a file called param.ifs - mine does not. If you find it ... this is the second splash that pops up right after the initial manufacturer's logo. This can be modified, as well as the boot animation. Know what you're doing if you want to change them.

Comment: Any clue about change boot logo Programatically  ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Slightly longer answer: An application has no business changing system-wide settings like the boot logo, so even if you can, you really really shouldn't.

Even longer answer: While it is technically not possible to change the boot logo/animation in ordinary usage of the phone, it *is* possible to do if you have a rooted phone and don't mind installing a custom ROM. Depending on a whole lot of factors, it might be doable with just root access. For details on how to do this, visit: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1745297.

Comment: Thank you kanchi,i agree with you,but is there any alternative way to do so?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can change boot logo on samsung is on directory mmt/.lfs/logo.jpg

Comment: Please provide more detail in your answer.